# How to add a function to a class using a decorator

Tags: javascript, decorator, es6-class, ecmascript-next

I'm trying to create an class decorator that simply adds a function (or property really) to a class, but having no joy.

```
const findDecorator = () => {
  return (constructor) => {
    constructor.prototype.findMe = () => console.log('You found me!')
  }
}
```

I've also tried using a `target.prototype` pattern and some other things, but to no use. Does anyone have a simple example of how to do this? By the way, I am also extending a class:

```
@findDecorator()
export default class MyClass extends OtherClass {
  shouldFireFirst () {
    this.findMe()
  }
}
```

EDIT: Actually, it looks like the issue is that the function is available on the instance, but not in the class declaraction.

Comment: Decorators are not part of any releases of the language yet.

Comment: @FelixKling What are you saying? It's not possible using Babel?

Comment: No, Babel supports it, but it’s not part of ES6.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments, and assuming you're using Babel along with `babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy`, what you're trying to do is add new methods to the target class. In order to do so, you'd need to extend the target class in your decorator, like so:

```
const findDecorator = (target) => {
   return class extends target {
        constructor(...args) {
            super();
        }

        findMe() { console.log('You found me!') }
    };
}

@findDecorator
export default class MyClass extends OtherClass {
  shouldFireFirst () {
    this.findMe()
  }
}

new MyClass().shouldFireFirst()  // => You found me!
```

If you need to pass params to your decorator, you can also do that:

```
const findDecorator = (name) => (target) => {
   return class extends target {
        constructor(...args) {
            super();
            this.name = name
        }

        findMe() { console.log(`You found ${this.name}!`) }
    };
}

@findDecorator('Waldo')
export default class MyClass extends OtherClass {
  shouldFireFirst () {
    this.findMe()
  }
}

new MyClass().shouldFireFirst()  // => You found Waldo!
```